# AWS Athena doesn't recognize FIRST_VALUE() as aggrigate expression

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am working on a query where I want to get the last time a value is submitted for a particular timepoint. This should be fairly easy using the aggregate function LAST_VALUE, however when I use the function AWS Athena doesn't recognize the function as an aggregate function gives me this error.

```
'"first_value"(cv.delay) OVER (PARTITION BY cv.trip_id ORDER BY cv.timestamp DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

When I try to add the aggregate function it also breaks saying that GROUP BY cannot accept aggregate functions. So depending on whether it is in the SELECT or GROUP BY it is both an aggregate and a non aggregate clause.

Has anyone successfully worked with a query like this in Athena?

My Query

```
select 
    cv.trip_id as trip_id
    ,cv.route_id as route_id
    ,cv.route_long_name as route_long_name
    ,cv.route_short_name as routes_short_name
    ,cv.direction_id as direction_id
--  ,cv.route_type as route_type
    ,max(cv.delay) as delay_max
    ,min(cv.delay) as delay_min 
    ,from_unixtime(cv.timestamp)
    ,first_value(cv.delay)
        over(partition by cv.trip_id
        order by cv.timestamp desc
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
        as last_delay
from stats_vehicles cv
where 
    cv.year = 2021
    and cv.month = 10
    and cv.day = 22
group by cv.trip_id,
    cv.timestamp,
    cv.route_id,
    cv.route_long_name,
    cv.route_short_name,
    cv.direction_id
```

Athena Example of LAST_VALUE

```
select venuestate, venueseats, venuename,
last_value(venuename)
over(partition by venuestate
order by venueseats desc
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
from (select * from venue where venueseats >0)
order by venuestate;
```

[LAST_VALUE/FIRST_VALUE Athena Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html)

UPDATE:
I attempted to add in the subquery to avoid adding last_delay in the group by clause, but I get the same error as above.

subquery statement:

```
select 
    cv.last_delay,
    cv.stop_id,
    cv.trip_id
from
    (select 
        cv.trip_id as trip_id
        ,cv.route_id as route_id
        ,cv.route_long_name as route_long_name
        ,cv.route_short_name as routes_short_name
        ,cv.direction_id as direction_id
    --  ,cv.route_type as route_type
        ,max(cv.delay) as delay_max
        ,min(cv.delay) as delay_min 
        ,from_unixtime(cv.timestamp)
        ,first_value(cv.delay)
            over(partition by cv.trip_id
            order by cv.timestamp desc
            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
            as last_delay
    from stats_vehicles cv
    where 
        cv.year = 2021
        and cv.month = 10
        and cv.day = 22
    group by cv.trip_id,
        cv.timestamp,
        cv.route_id,
        cv.route_long_name,
        cv.route_short_name,
        cv.direction_id
        ) as cv
group by
    cv.trip_id,
    cv.stop_id,
    cv.last_delay
```

I also attempted to use min as a placeholder for the aggregate function, but it says that you cannot nest window functions inside aggrigation.

```
 Cannot nest window functions inside aggregation 'min': ["first_value"(cv.delay) OVER (PARTITION BY cv.trip_id ORDER BY cv.timestamp DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)]
```

aggrigation query:

```
select 
    cv.trip_id as trip_id
    ,cv.route_id as route_id
    ,cv.route_long_name as route_long_name
    ,cv.route_short_name as routes_short_name
    ,cv.direction_id as direction_id
    ,max(cv.delay) as delay_max
    ,min(cv.delay) as delay_min 
    ,from_unixtime(cv.timestamp)
    ,min(first_value(cv.delay)
        over(partition by cv.trip_id
        order by cv.timestamp desc
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)) as last_delay
from (select * from stats_vehicles
where 
    year = 2021
    and month = 10
    and day = 22) cv
group by cv.trip_id,
    cv.timestamp,
    cv.route_id,
    cv.route_long_name,
    cv.route_short_name,
    cv.direction_id
```

Here is some sample data. The data is being sent from buses and are GPS signals from sensors reporting every 60 seconds. The each bus has a route id and trip id associated with it at any given moment. I have broken out each arrival for each stop at any given moment to have the estimated delay. The thought is to get the last delay reported for each trip for each stop to get the most accurate arrival of each bus for each trip.

The sample data below is what is being sent every 60 seconds.
[image: sample data]

Comment: Can you please post some example values and expected output, cause currently I can't make much sense of your query? Are there multiple `delay` values present for some `trip_id`? Are there `null` values present for `delay`? Also `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` makes the window being the whole subset i.e value would be the same for all rows with the same `trip_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding cv.delay to the group by?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not return what I am looking for. I have updated the question to provide more context on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

Athena recognizes the `first_value` window function but can't use it inside select for `group by` result. You need move it to subselect and use the subquery result to `group by`:

```
select ..., last_delay  
from 
(
  select *, first_value... as last_delay  
  from stats_vehicles cv
  where condition
)
group by ..., last_delay
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to like these recomendations that you have given me. Or maybe I need to update the syntax to fit my specific example. Could you be a bit more clear with your recommendations in the outlined queries above?

Comment: @AvidDabbler you have the same error in subquery cause you use `group by` in subquery, the whole point of subquery - to use `first_value` without `group by` as I wrote in my answer. The second example does not have any `group by` in subquery.

Comment: @AvidDabbler removed incorrect suggestion about aggregation function. Thought have worked around with it sometime ago the similar problem but it seems that my memory failed me)